# How to compile HelloWorld application included in skia?

Tags: skia

How do I compile skia HelloWorld program?

I went through this [guide](https://skia.org/user/build) - it doesn't mention how to build `example/HelloWorld`

The version I have checked out is:

```
c7b263b603107acdb16b6570989e1ce5a2c7eb4e
```

I see mentions of it inside the `.gn` files but I am not sure how to invoke that specific item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HelloWorld program will be build as part of the normal Skia build process ([Reference](https://skia.org/user/build)) for debug builds.

In the Skia source directory:

- Sync the third-party dependencies with `python2 tools/git-sync-deps`
- Generate the build files with `bin/gn gen out/Debug`.

  - If you run into problems with Python 2 vs 3 here (i.e. when it complains about syntax errors in the build script), you would have to set Python 2 as the default. Instructions on how to achieve this might vary depending on your setup. You could look e.g. [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=skia-git) for an example approach (creating a temporary bin directory with symlinks `python` and `python-config` to `/usr/bin/python2` and `/usr/bin/python2-config`, then prepending this temporary directory to the `$PATH`).
- Start the build process with `ninja -C out/Debug`. This will build all targets including `HelloWorld`.

  - To only build `HelloWorld` (and its dependencies), you could directly invoke `ninja -C out/Debug HelloWorld`.
- The resulting binary is in `out/Debug/HelloWorld`.

Comment: Thanks, note: I could only get it to work under out/Release

Comment: Skia Hello World is not depending on the official external expediencies/interfaces. Which is a very bad example! I think the worst example seen of a "getting started".